# How to search for a string from a file in java?

Tags: java

I have written a program to download a file in java.
Now i need to search for a string in that file and if the search is true it should notify through email.
And  furthermore have to schedule this program..
Needed Help

Comment: What kind of help do you need? What problems are you having? What code is not working for you? Can you post the problem code?

Answer (score 5):

Well, you've got several different tasks there:

- Loading data from a file (possibly streaming it)
- Searching for a string within loaded data
- Emailing the notification to the user
- Scheduling

Focus on one problem at a time. If you get stuck on one problem, ask a *specific* question here, saying what you've done so far (but only related to that single problem) and where you're stuck.

Comment: +1 I bet you can find info (with examples) on how to do each of these tasks by searching this site.

Answer (score 2):

For searching file you can do something like this:

```
    Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean containsString=false;
    System.out.println("Enter string to search :");
    String searchWrd=s.next();
    Scanner readFile =new Scanner(new File("/../fileName"));//enter appropriate file   location
    readFile.useDelimiter("\\s+");
    while(readFile.hasNext())
        if(searchWrd.equals(readFile.next()))
        {
            containsString=true;
            break;
        }
    if(containsString)
        System.out.println("Contains searched word");
    else 
        System.out.println("Doesnot contain searched word");
```

and for mailing you can consider [JavaMail](http://www.google.co.in/search?hl=en&safe=active&q=Javamail&aq=f&aqi=g10&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=).I didn't understand what is meant by scheduling.